# how to add array object inside another array in angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created a form using formbuilder. I tried to create data array object into users object, but it's adding as a object inside users array. Below is my code

```js
export class AppComponent  {
  users = [ { "firstname": "ramu", "lastname": "mothukuri", "city": "chennai", "street": "sivan koiil street", "pin": "600024","data":[{"company":"xyz","address":"yyy"}] },
  { "firstname": "ramu", "lastname": "mothukuri", "city": "chennai", "street": "sivan koiil street", "pin": "600024","data":[{"company":"xyz","address":"yyy"}] },
  { "firstname": "ramu", "lastname": "mothukuri", "city": "chennai", "street": "sivan koiil street", "pin": "600024","data":[{"company":"xyz","address":"yyy"}] }
  ]
  myForm: FormGroup;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { 
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
users: this.fb.array([])
})

let formArr = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls.users;
formArr.push(fb.group({
firstname: this.users[0].firstname,
lastname: this.users[0].lastname,
street: this.users[0].street,
data:this.users[0].data
}))
}

  onMy(form){

    console.log(form);
  }
}
```

I have attached the screen shot please check [image]

But i tried to write the code but i am not getting below is the expected format of json form values

Form values: {

```
 "users": [
    {
      "firstname": "ramu",
      "lastname": "mothukuri",
      "street": "sivan koiil street",
      "data": [{
        "company": "xyz",
        "address": "yyy"
      }]
    }
  ]
}
```

Below is the code URL

> [CODE URL](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-formgroup2-first?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: What is the format you are hoping to get?

Comment: Below is the format to get, just i want to get data as a array of object [
    {
      "firstname": "ramu",
      "lastname": "mothukuri",
      "street": "sivan koiil street",
      "data":[ {
        "company": "xyz",
        "address": "yyy"
      }]
    }
  ]
}

Comment: Your question is sooooooooooo confusing...

Comment: coool, just i want to format data as a array object, currently i got below format-data": { "company": "xyz", "address": "yyy" }  expected format is data":[ { "company": "xyz", "address": "yyy" }].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare data as a formArray

```
 let dataArr = new FormArray([]);
    dataArr.push(new FormGroup({
      'company': new FormControl(this.users[0].data[0].company),
      'address': new FormControl(this.users[0].data[0].address)
    }));


    let formArr = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls.users;
    formArr.push(fb.group({
      firstname: this.users[0].firstname,
      lastname: this.users[0].lastname,
      street: this.users[0].street,
      data: dataArr
    }));
```

Comment: no, already i got form values, but i need set data as a array of object

Comment: Current format [ { "firstname": "ramu", "lastname": "mothukuri", "street": "sivan koiil street", "data": { "company": "xyz", "address": "yyy" }} ] }, expected format is [ { "firstname": "ramu", "lastname": "mothukuri", "street": "sivan koiil street", "data":[ { "company": "xyz", "address": "yyy" }] } ] }

Answer (score 0):

In your form group declaration in the control data create an another formgroup instead of just value.

```
let formArr = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls.users;
formArr.push(fb.group({
  firstname: this.users[0].firstname,
  lastname: this.users[0].lastname,
  street: this.users[0].street,
  data:this.fb.group({
     company: this.users[0].data.company, 
     address: this.users[0].data.address })
}))
}
```

This way you will get data as array.